# How to get VBA to replace dates later than 05/04/2016 with 05/04/2016

Tags: vba, excel, date

this is my first question here, so I will be as clear as possible.

I have a large dataset in Excel, and one column that I am particularly interested in has comments such as "Hello, the date this product is released is 08/04/2017" for example. I am looking to create a Code that will allow me to change every date in those cells to 05/04/2016.

Edit: Just to be clear, each cell may or may not contain more than one date!

The Code will ideally identify any date after 05/04/2016 in the cell and chance it to 05/04/2016, without touching any of the text that isnt a date, or date before 05/04/2016 in that cell.

Here is the code that I have been working with, if it helps at all,

Sub `ReplaceDate()`

Dim x As Date

For x = 6 / 4 / 2016 To 05 / 04 / 2020

```
Range("C2:C31").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
Selection.Replace "x", Replacement:="05/04/2016", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Next x

End Sub

As you have probably guessed, right now the code actually replaces any "X's" within the cell, but I have tried things like `Selection.Replace DataValue > 05/04/2016` and such.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Kind regards.

Comment: is there only one date per cell and is it always the last "word" of the sentence?

Comment: I apologise, each cell may or may not contain more than one date, sorry that I wasn't specific about that. Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try:

```
Sub ChangeDate()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim words As Variant
    Dim iWord As Long

    For Each cell In Range("C2", Cells(Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp)) '<--| loop through column C cells from row 2 down to last not empty one
        words = Split(cell, " ")
        For iWord = 0 To UBound(words)
            If IsDate(words(iWord)) Then If CDate(words(iWord)) > CDate("05/04/2016") Then words(iWord) = "05/04/2016"
        Next
        cell.Value = Join(words, " ")
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @Ian, if my answer solves your question then please accept it by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. thank you

Comment: @Ian, I edited answer after your clarification. If it solves your question I'd appreciate you marked it as accepted. thank you

Comment: Thank you so much, this was a great help! If you want to message me sometime, I would love to take to you about VBA. Have a great end to your weekend and I marked your comment. Thanks again!